# How fix the function to avoid error logs (Undefined offset: 2 in ....) - explode

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this in my function:

```
$str = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // it gets: /cart/invisible/
$bits = explode('/',$str);
$num = $bits[2];
```

A problem is that it return mi error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in
>   /public_html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/functions.php on line 3.

P. S. I just checked the information from "a possible duplicate" and there is not exist even any similar example.

How can I fix it?

Comment: @TobiasF. No, it is not. Before I checked a many similar topics before ask my question.

Comment: What do you expect as the answer from your code?

Comment: @NigelRen Hi. I have what I want... but it returns be "PHP Notice" which I want to prevent.

I want to take a string from "/cart/invisible/" - I want to have "invisible" - there can be any different word e.g "invisible-now" etc.

And my options works well, but returns PHP Notice. :) And now I want to avoid it.

Comment: `$num =end($bits)` , do this work?

Comment: Hi @Shahin - Unfortunately not.  It does not return this what I want.

Comment: you want to get the last item or just remove the notice?

Comment: I want to get the last item and remove the notice :)

Comment: `@$num = $bits[2];` or `$num = $bits[2] ?? "";` :)

Comment: @Shahin `$num = $bits[2] ?? ""`; works for me! :) Thank you for your help! P.S. You learned me a new thing in PHP!

Comment: You're welcome :) , also for the first code it should be `$num = @$bits[2];` but I can't edit the comment.

Comment: `$num = @$bits[2];` also works perfect! Thank you for your time and your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you explode `$str` you get an array indexed from `0` to `n` as result. When you try to access an index that is not available an error occurs.

```
$bits = explode('/',$str);
var_dump($bits);
```

Try `var_dump` and you can see the array indexes after exploding. Check if it has an index `2`.

**UPDATE**

```
$num = isset( $bits[2] ) ? $bits[2] : "";
```

Comment: Hi,  thank you for your reply.

I got it:

`array(4) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(6) "cart" [2]=> string(14) "invisible" [3]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: Hi @melvin - Unfortunately not. I thought I solved it, but unfortunately not... Still "PHP Notice" appears.

Comment: can you share what is in $str and what do you get when you `var_dump( $bits[1] );`

Comment: I got this `string(6) "cart"` - but I want to get `invisible`

Comment: Then you would surely get `$bit[2]` as `invisible`. To avoid notice or error, just check the update part of my answer.

Comment: If the value was in element 2 of the array, there should be no notice.  Getting an *Undefined offset* message and the value doesn't make sense.

Comment: @NigelRen i just suggested to use `isset` inorder to avoid the notice which is a best practice.

Answer (score 1):

The array index starts from `0`, so and you are calling `$bits[2]` which does not exists as your example will return only two elements, try using as `$bits[1]`

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately if I change for '$bits[1]' - I do not get my result. I am using it to get from url word "invisible" - but it can be also different word.

Answer (score 1):

If you have var_dumped the `$bits` variable and got this:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(6) "cart" [2]=> string(14) "invisible" [3]=> string(0) "" }
```

as you commented on another answer...
Then `$bits[2]` definitely exists.

The notice must be raised when the code is executed from some other context then you think.

Anyway, you should not just access `$bits[2]` blindlessly. You should check if it is there first, and if it is not do whatever is appropriate in your use case.
And also you should not rely just on `bits[2]`. The entire path identifies your endpoint. Well not sure what your overall goal is, but you should check that it is `invisible` only if it is `cart` and maybe also that there is nothing more after the invisible like `/cart/invisible/xyz/` maybe should not be identified as the thing...

Comment: Hi,

Actually you are right! Because the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` sometimes returns `/cart/invisibile/?add_it` - that why it could returns the notice. :) Thank you for your answer! Next time I will specify my question!

Comment: @kibus90 I'm afraid that for `/cart/invisibile/?add_it` it would again yield $bits[2] as expected. There must be yet another context... To raise the notice the input string (the request uri) must contain at most one `/` character.